# Vue event bus emit object not passed to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm emitting an object via event bus to the parent and then assigning that object to my `detail` variable which is to be passed as a prop to my `ContactDetail` component, but the prop isn't getting the updated object.

`ContactCard` is a component imported in `ContactList`.

Getting the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "contactDetail" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

ContactCard

```
<script>
import {bus} from "../../bus.js";

export default {
    name: "ContactCard",
    methods: {
        showDetails: function(event) {
            bus.$emit('showDetails', { pfp: this.pfp, name: this.name, address: this.address });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

AddressBook

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <ContactList v-if="!showDetail"></ContactList>
        <ContactDetail v-else :contactDetail="details"></ContactDetail>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { bus } from "../bus.js";
import ContactList from "../components/addressBook/ContactList.vue";
import ContactDetail from "../components/addressBook/ContactDetail.vue";

export default {
    name: "AddressBook",
    components: {
        ContactList,
        ContactDetail
    },
    data() {
        return {
            showDetail: false,
            details: {}
        }
    },
    created() {
        bus.$on('showDetails', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.showDetail = true;
            this.details = Object.assign({}, this.details, data);
            console.log(this.details);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

ContactDetail

```
<template>
    <div class="detail-container">
        {{contactDetail}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "ContactDetail",
    data() {``
        return {
            details: ''
        }
    },
    props: {
        contactDetail: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    watch: {
        contactDetail(newVal, prevVal) {
            this.details = newVal;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Why isn't the `contactDetails` prop updated in `ContactDetail`?

Comment: We don't see any contactDetails aside from the error?

Comment: @Wimanicesir my bad that was a typo in copying the error message. I also added the ContactDetail.vue code.

Comment: I don't know if this is still a "problem" with vue, but properties should be defined as snakeCase as you did but you should be used as kebab case (dash-case) so `:contactDetail` should be `:contact-detail` [reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-name-casing-strongly-recommended)

Comment: @drocha87  I'm not having that issue with other props in other components though.

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to do with the life cycle and `v-else`. Cause the error says it's rendering before the prop is defined. So seems like `v-else` renders and then `this.details` is being updated. But by that point, it's already rendered. Just a hunch.

Comment: @Soubriquet if you remove the if else condition the problem still occurs?

Comment: Yeah...wait actually that's super weird. I changed it to this `<ContactDetail :test="test"></ContactDetail>` and getting the same error.

Comment: Oh fuck....I'm dumb. I accidentally had two script sections.... instead of a style section. So the second script was empty....woops. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally had two script sections instead of script and style.

Before

```
<template>
    <div class="detail-container">
        {{details}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { bus } from "../../bus.js";
export default {
    name: "ContactDetail",
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    props: {
        details: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
}
</script>

<script>
</script>
```

After

```
<template>
    <div class="detail-container">
        hellow
        {{details}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { bus } from "../../bus.js";
export default {
    name: "ContactDetail",
    data() {
        return {
            pfp: "",
            name: "",
            address: ""
        }
    },
    props: {
        details: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```